# Inform clients via web service

Tags: .net, vb.net, service, client

I have written an application in .NET and built a web service to use the functionality in an iOS app as well. It should be inform all clients who are connected to the web service if something has changed. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like Socket.io to keep a connection between client and server and in that way push notices to the client.
Or just make the client send a request to the server every now and then and ask if there is anything that have changed.

Comment: Thanks fpr your answer!

Comment: Feel free to mark it as correct if it gave you the info you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yah but clients will have to check your web service (polling) to see if there is any modifications.
Keep another function in web service for that. 
Approach should depend on the fact that how often changes happen and is it need to inform real time.